# How to receive data in recyclerview from other recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle, android-recyclerview

First lets say that Im a beginner in Android and my english is basic, I can understand the answers but maybe my way to write is not the usual or correct.

So, let go to my question:

Im doing a project for a course and I have done a first recyclerview with "pets", every pet has a button where you can give "likes" and these  "likes" will be saved in a textview.

I have a second recyclerview, similar to the first one, this second one will show the 5 last pets I gave "likes" in the first recyclerview.

I need to show in the second recyclerview the "likes" I gave to every pet in the first recyclerview. How I can do this?  How I can receive these data in every element of the recyclerview? Do I need a second adapter, or another arrayList?

My code works perfectly till the moment I try to receive data, then the app fall, I tryed a lot of ways but Im not sure what I am doing wrong. (I have this problems with the recyclerviews, I just see is not the same way I did with other acitivities that didnt have a recyclerview).

Below I let you see some codes:

Inside onCreate in MainActivity.class

```
public void inicializarLista(){

        mascotasList = new ArrayList<Mascotas>();

        mascotasList.add(new Mascotas(R.drawable.loro,"Coti el loro"));
        mascotasList.add(new Mascotas(R.drawable.hamster,"El Ghamster"));
        mascotasList.add(new Mascotas(R.drawable.tortuga,"Turtle Ninja"));
        mascotasList.add(new Mascotas(R.drawable.perro,"Mochi"));
        mascotasList.add(new Mascotas(R.drawable.conejo,"Bonny"));
    }

     public MascotasAdapter adapter;
     public void inicializarAdaptador(){
        adapter = new MascotasAdapter(this, mascotasList);
        mascotaRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void cliclearBoton(){
        ImageButton favoritas = findViewById(R.id.favoritasCinco);

        favoritas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView cantLikes = findViewById(R.id.tvCantidad);
                String dlikes = cantLikes.getText().toString();
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MascotasFavoritas.class);
                i.putExtra("loslikes", dlikes);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
```

Below my onBindViewHolder in MascotaAdapter.class

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final MascotasViewHolder mascotasHolder, final int position) {

        final Mascotas mascotasList = mascotas.get(position);

        mascotasHolder.imFoto.setImageResource(mascotasList.getIvFoto());
        mascotasHolder.textNombre.setText(mascotasList.getNombre());

        mascotasHolder.ibDarLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Snackbar.make(v,"Diste like a "+ mascotasList.getNombre(),Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                int plusLike = Integer.parseInt(mascotasHolder.textCantidadLikes.getText().toString());
                mascotasHolder.textCantidadLikes.setText(String.valueOf(plusLike + 1));
            }
        });
    }
 EjecutarAmpliar
```

And below the functions I have inside onCreate in MascotaFavoritas.class, (here I want receive the data).

```
 void inicializarFavoritas(){
        favoritasList = new ArrayList<Mascotas>();

        favoritasList.add(new Mascotas(R.drawable.perro,"Mochi"));
        favoritasList.add(new Mascotas(R.drawable.conejo,"Bonny"));
        favoritasList.add(new Mascotas(R.drawable.loro,"Coti el loro"));
        favoritasList.add(new Mascotas(R.drawable.hamster,"El Ghamster"));
        favoritasList.add(new Mascotas(R.drawable.tortuga,"Turtle Ninja"));

    }

    public MascotasAdapter adapter;
    public void inicializarAdaptador(){
        adapter = new MascotasAdapter(this, favoritasList);
        favoritasRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    public void recibirLikes(){
        TextView receptorLikes = findViewById(R.id.tvCantidad);
        Bundle parametros = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        String datoLike = parametros.getString("loslikes");
        receptorLikes.setText(datoLike);
    }
```

Thank you guys if you can help me, and sorry for my bad way to write in english. I appreciate your help.

Comment: data stays in your datasources not in recyclerview , use your datasource into your recycler views

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question. The two recyclerViews are on separate activities am I correct. If it is so, you can pass data from the recycler view to the new activity where you can set the recyclerview data based on what you recieved from last activity. Now since the type of data both the recycler view are using are different. You need to use two separate recycler view.